Do you say "swimming teacher"?
I remember someone told me that we only use "teacher" for school subjects such as English, math or science but not for sport subjects such as swimming or basketball.
For sports, we often use "coach" or "instructor".
For example, I am learning to swim with a swimming instructor / coach.
I think an instructor gives basic swimming skills to anyone from children to adults. A coach gives more professional swimming skills often to a more talented swimmer.
But I often see articles using "swimming / swim teacher" which sound a little odd. Maybe, it is more common in American English.
Do you say "swimming teacher"?
If you do, is it the same as "swimming instructor"?

Google Ngrams shows that 'swimming teacher' is actually less common in American English (but used in both).

If you can't swim, you get a teacher to teach you how to swim. If swim well and you want to race, you get a coach. AmE tends to pare down many ing words.

In the UK (British English) the job title 'swimming teacher' is the most commonly used, and it is interchangeable with 'swimming coach' and 'swimming instructor'

Swimming teacher
Alternative titles for this job include
Swimming coach, swimming instructor
Swimming teachers help people learn how to swim, improve their
swimming skills and exercise in water.

UK Government Careers Service: Swimming Teacher

I'd suggest that "teacher" suggests someone who teaches children swimming for pleasure, fittness and safety.  "Coach" suggest someone who teaches competitive swimming

Since @Tom didn't specify which regional dialect they are looking for, I'll just add that in the US, Swim Instructor or Swimming Instructor is the most common term, although everyone would know what you mean by Swimming Teacher as well. In the US, a Swim Coach is (as James said), someone who teaches competitive swimming.
